# Is it possible to manipulate multiple graphs with one manipulate function?

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I'm trying to find a way to manipulate a function and its derivative, but two variables of the function change. Is there a way to manipulate multiple graphs with the same set of parameters? Meaning, if I increase a variable for the function, the derivative will adjust to it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Take a look at `Manipulate`. On http://www.demonstrations.wolfram.com you can find lots and lots of examples on what you can do with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this...

```
f[n_, x_] := Sin[2 Pi n x];
g[n_, x_] := D[f[n, x], x]; 
Manipulate[Plot[{f[n , x], Evaluate[g[n, x]]}, {x, 1, 10}], {n, 0.5, 4}]
```

Comment: This works very well. Thank you. I can't up-vote you because I don't have reputation.

Comment: @AnonE.Muss. you can, however, accept the answer, To do so, click on the check mark that appears under down arrow to the left of this answer.

Comment: sweet! there, I did it .